# How to add sub array in a JSON file?

Tags: arrays, json

I have a result json file namely result.json and I would to insert another sub array in total and rows.

This is my JSON File 
{"total":"9","rows":[
            {"id":"16","firstname":"Melanie","lastname":"Toledo","phone":"091919191","email":"test@gmail.com"},         {"id":"29","firstname":"x","lastname":"x","phone":"1","email":"test@gmail.com"},            {"id":"30","firstname":"y","lastname":"y","phone":"2","email":"test@gmail.vp"},         {"id":"31","firstname":"xxx","lastname":"xxxx","phone":"12345","email":"test@gmail.com"},           {"id":"33","firstname":"xy","lastname":"xy","phone":"1","email":"test@gmail.com"},          {"id":"34","firstname":"yyy","lastname":"yyy","phone":"2","email":"test@gmail.com"},            {"id":"35","firstname":"n","lastname":"n","phone":"1","email":"test@gmail.com"},            {"id":"36","firstname":"q","lastname":"q","phone":"1","email":"x@g.com"},           {"id":"37","firstname":"","lastname":"","phone":"","email":""}
        ]
}

Here is my code

```
<?php
$current_data = file_get_contents('result.json');
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);
$extra['rows'] = array (
        'id'        =>  '101',
        'firstname' =>  'marlon',
        'lastname'  =>  'berces',
        'phone'     =>  '12',
        'email'     =>  'test@gmail.com'
        );
        $array_data[] = $extra;
        $final_data = json_encode($array_data);
        file_put_contents('result.json',$final_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you will need to add the new row in the current list of rows, and after that, you have to update the sum, as this is all static data that came from the file.

```
<?php
// Read json
$current_data = file_get_contents('result.json');
$array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);

// New row
$extra = array(
    'id'        =>  '101',
    'firstname' =>  'marlon',
    'lastname'  =>  'berces',
    'phone'     =>  '12',
    'email'     =>  'test@gmail.com'
);

// Add the new row
$array_data['rows'][] = $extra;

// Update the sum
$array_data['total'] = count($array_data['rows']);

// Write json
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);
file_put_contents('result.json',$final_data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by convert it an array then use array_push for add new value agani convert to json...

Comment: write code first for read file store it to varibale after that convert to array then use array push to add new record again convert to json and write in your file now find for all these step there is avalable this methods on stack over flow

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the **Array.prototype.push()** method(In JavaScript). Or if you are using PHP, then **array_push()**.

The push()/array_push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Seems @nezhar beat me to it :)